# If I cannot call a destructor in C#, what is the solution to destroying an object for the sake of security?

Tags: c#

```
CustomerData newObject = new CustomerData(long number)//takes credit card #
//uses newObject
//need to delete object here?
```

I am creating an object that will hold customer information; the object will call a method to out that info in a database. When I am done how do I get rid of the object?

Comment: `simple newObject = null should clear out the memory` It will mark it as eligible for GC @Alen.Toma - but it will still likely exist in memory until the GC gets to it.

Comment: If you want to get rid of data as soon as possible, ensure the scope of the variable is as small as possible. You don't need to `= null` if the object's reference is lost at the end of the method scope

Comment: @Alen.Toma: As mjwills said, setting a object to null does not say anything about it being collected. That is **why** we have Disposing in the first place. The GC does not like to waste time running. So if it only runs on application closure, that is usually a ideal case.

Comment: @Alen.Toma GC is what takes data out of memory. Not IDisposable, not setting the reference to null. If you don't care about GC why are you even commenting?

Comment: This question is too fury, you will need to clear the memory for every allocation of that number, this is not a trivial concept as a number is a value type and gets copied all over the place, one way is to use unsafe and pointers and make sure you clear the (actual memory), even then you will probably miss places

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly an attacker that can read the information **out of memory**, has propably beaten your security already. You can not use the information unless it is clear and unencrypted in memory. And an attacker that can read the memory can just read it then. And even if you get all the references to that instance removed, the bit pattern is still written in the RAM - until it is overwritten by something on pure chance.

I also can not think of any customer related number that I would consider "secure information". You write a person/groups Customer Number onto every bill you send them. If you did not, you could not use it in any meaningfull way for processing.

There are fringe cases where strings are security relevant and that is what SecureString covers. You know, Passwords. But beyond that most types are irrelevant.

Answer (score -3):

You can dereference an object using in C#

> object = null;

Then you can force Garbage Collection to collect using

> GC.Collect();

**But it is not recommended. It's bad.**

Actually, object = nothing does not delete it at all.

> object = null;

will discard the reference to it, which will speed up when it will be cleaned up by the garbage collector, but **you can't know when that will be**.

If an object has a **Dispose()** method, you need to call it before it goes out of scope.  You can use the **using** keyword to do this for you automatically

> using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromBitmap(bm))
>
> {
>
> //some code
>
> } // gr.Dispose() is called here

Comment: `which will speed up when it will be cleaned up by the garbage collector` That is not always true. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cbrumme/2003/04/19/lifetime-gc-keepalive-handle-recycling/

Comment: Good intention, but you cannot `object = null;` a Struct